# compare time in sql/oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

if taken_time column i.e-(complete_time- Create_time) is less or equals to 240hours then SLA is 'IN' else 'out'

Example:

| Create_Date_time | complete_date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 06-02-2021 12:01:00 | 06-02-2021 14:02:00 |
| 07-02-2021 1:01:00 | 07-02-2021 10:02:00 |

expected output:

| Create_Date_time | complete_date_time | taken_time | SLA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06-02-2021 12:01:00 | 06-02-2021 14:02:00 | 02:01:00 | IN |
| 01-02-2021 01:01:00 | 10-02-2021 01:40:00 | 240:39:00 | OUT |

so we have to first calculate taken time and then SLA on the basis of taken_time.
the create_Day_time and complete_date_time is stored in database as per format of oracle storing date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to calculate `taken_time` to do this.  Instead, you can just use date arithmetic and comparisons:

```
select t.*,
       (case when complete_date_time > Create_Date_time + interval '240' hour
             then 'Out' else 'In'
        end) as in_out
from t;
```

You can also express this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when complete_date_time - Create_Date_time > 240 / 24
             then 'Out' else 'In'
        end) as in_out
from t;
```

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH BRO. its working perfectly fine but if i am changing 240 hour into 2880 then i am getting error -> the leading precision of the interval is too small.  means it is giving error for 4 digit numbers.

Comment: @NishantSaxena . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  At some point,  you should be measuring the time intervals using days rather than hours.

Comment: @NishantSaxena - interval literals where the number passed in is up to 9 digits are supported, but you must provide the precision in the expression. Like so: `interval '2880' hour(4)` - notice the 4 in parentheses, meaning "4 digits". If you feel that this requirement is idiotic on Oracle's part, I agree; but it's not that complicated. Also easy to find if you are in the good habit of checking the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For your info : Adding 24 hours to a date in Oracle is the same thing as adding 1 day. So if you want to change your logic and count in days you can use :

```
select Create_Date_time, complete_date_time, 
case when complete_date_time > Create_Date_time + 1 then 'In' else 'Out' end as SLA 
from YourTable
```

If you want to keep the count in hours, you can use :

```
select Create_Date_time, complete_date_time, 
case when complete_date_time > Create_Date_time + NumberOfHoursRequested * 1/24 then 'In' else 'Out' end as SLA 
from YourTable
```